# Git tracking branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, branching-and-merging, remote-branch

I have created a repository in local and pushed all the changes to the github.
Later i have created a new branch("git branch v2") called "v2" and did some modification and pushed that branch to github as well.
Later when i was executing the command "git remote show origin" i am getting the following output.

```
  * remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/mayuran19/se24_P03.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/mayuran19/se24_P03.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master tracked
    v2     tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
    v2     pushes to v2     (local out of date)
```

But when i was executing the command "git branch -vv" it is showing the the branch "v2" is not a tracking branch.

```
  master bad4ed9 [origin/master] Correct name
  * v2     6ec46b0 Data files
```

My question is, why the branch v2 is not showing as a tracked branch even though the remote branch is available in github and i am able to do the pull and push of this branch?

The output of the command "git branch -a" shows the following output

```
  master
* v2
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/v2
```

But not showing the mapping between the local and remote branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we need a few definitions.

A *local* branch (also just called "a branch", with no modifier) is one whose full name starts with `refs/heads/`.  When using `git branch`, you will see your local branches by default.  The `git branch` command strips off the `refs/heads/` part, leaving you with names like `master` and `v2`.

A *remote-tracking* branch is one whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/` (and then has the name of a remote after that).  When using `git branch -r`, the command will show you your remote-tracking branches.  The `git branch -r` command strips off the `refs/remotes/` part, leaving you with names like `origin/master` and `origin/v2`.

The prefix-stripping works both ways: `git branch` takes it off, and you can leave it off too.  This is meant for convenience, and works well as long as you do not accidentally give your (regular, local) branches names starting with `origin/`.  (If you do accidentally name a local branch `origin/abc`, for instance, you may confuse yourself and git's helpful stripping of prefixes becomes harmful.)

(Note that all these entities are local to your own repository, despite the name "remote-tracking".  Additional references may also exist and you can see all of them with `git for-each-ref`, which will show you every reference using its full name.  Most of the time you don't need this, and `git branch` suffices.)

A (regular, local) branch can be set to *track* another branch.  Making one branch track another does a few things for you, such as make `git status` tell you when you are ahead and/or behind, and including the other branch in `git branch -vv` output.  (Setting tracking is not the same as a remote-tracking branch.  Again, a local branch is one whose name starts with `refs/heads/`, and its name does not change whether or not it is set to track another branch.  However, the terminology is certainly confusing.)

To make one branch track another, first check out the first branch (the one you want to do the tracking).  Then, run `git branch --set-upstream-to otherbranch`.  For instance, to make `v2` track `origin/v2`:

```
git checkout v2
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/v2
```

To make a local branch track another local branch, simply use a local branch name rather than a remote-tracking branch name.  To make a local branch stop tracking anything, use `git branch --unset-upstream`.

There's one more trick to all of this,<sup>1</sup> which is that when you ask `git checkout` to check out (but not create) a local branch that does not exist, `git checkout` will search to see if there is a remote-tracking branch with a similar name.  If so, it will *create* the local branch *and* set it up to track the remote-tracking branch.  That is, if branch `v2` *does not* exist—for instance, if you rename or delete the existing local `v2`—and `origin/v2` still *does* exist, then:

```
git checkout v2
```

*creates* local branch `v2` *and* sets it to track `origin/v2`, all at once.

A branch need not track another branch to push and fetch/merge/rebase/pull, but setting it up as tracking can make all of those operations more convenient.

---

<sup>1</sup>As usual with git, there are actually more methods to make local branches track something else.  You can set up a local branch to track a remote-tracking branch on a successful `git push` by adding `-u` to the push.  You can use the (deprecated) `git branch --set-upstream` command.  You can use flags to `git checkout` or `git branch` to create or re-create a branch with tracking set.  And, you can use `git config` (with two separate `git config` commands) to make a local branch track some other branch.

Comment: Good answer. I wonder why git does not set the tracking for a new local branch when `git push` from that branch?

Comment: @Artyom: `git push` *will* set the upstream *if* you add the `-u` flag, as I noted in the footnote.  This feature was new in git 1.7.0.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR `v2` is not a tracked branch - no upstream is set. `pull` won't work (the way you think). `push` works due to default push rules.

> My question is, why the branch v2 is not showing as a tracked branch

If you look at your .git/config, you'll see a `branch "master"` stanza with tracking info, but you won't see a `branch "v2"` stanza, i.e. `v2` isn't a tracking branch.

> even though the remote branch is available in github

Pushing a non-tracking branch doesn't make it a tracking branch automatically. You need to add `-u` to your push to do that. You probably meant to do this the first time you pushed a non-tracking branch:

```
$ git push -u origin v2
```

> i am able to do the pull and push of this branch

`pull` won't do what you expect since `v2` doesn't track an upstream. It will update the remote tracking branch `origin/v2` in your local repo, but it won't reconcile (merge or rebase) the local commits in the local `v2` branch with any new commits made on the remote.  However, if no one else is making updates to the `v2` branch on the remote, then you probably won't notice an issue.

`push` works because of the default push rules, which matches up based on branch names.

> ```
> Remote branches:
>    master tracked
>    v2     tracked
>  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
>    master merges with remote master
>  Local refs configured for 'git push':
>    master pushes to master (local out of date)
>    v2     pushes to v2     (local out of date)
> ```

- `Remote branches:` section shows the remote tracking branch `origin/v2`in your local repo tracks the remote's branch `v2`. (The remote tracking branch `origin/v2` is different from your local `v2` branch.)
- `Local branch configured ...` section shows only local branch `master` is affected by `pull`, i.e. `master` tracks remote `master`.  `v2` is not listed - `pull` won't affect it because it has no upstream set.
- `Local refs configured ...` section shows your `v2` branch will push/update to the remote's `v2` (and update `origin/v2`) - this is based on the push command's default matching rules (also depending on how your `push.default` config is set and what version of `git` you are using).

Note there's a little inconsistency or counterintuitive behavior between `push` and `pull`. Traditionally, `push` without a fully specified refspec arg, by default, doesn't care about the upstream - it simply pushes the same-named branch on the remote.  Since the tracked remote branch is often named the same as the local branch, things work and the `push` and `pull` commands appear to both use the configured tracking branch. However, `push` may not work as expected if the local branch and remote branch are named differently.  Certain changes to various versions of `git` with respect to `push` and `push.default`, i.e. `tracking`, `current`, and `simple`, try to reconcile those differences.

Additional reading:

- http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/
- http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/